# How to Log in Spring?

Tags: spring, logging

I've never been using logging, so I'm pretty ignorant about it. Anyway I've a Spring controller and I thought that it was as easy as adding this to the controller's class:

```
private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
```

where logger is org.slf4j.Logger and to log use:

```
logger.info("mainpage");
```

but nothing appears on the eclipse console. How do I do it?

I didn't configure log4j or anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to configure log4j, you will need the jar first. Then, place this in your web.xml:-

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/log4j.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

In this example, you will need to create your `log4j.xml`, something like this:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<log4j:configuration>
    <appender name="consoleAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%-5p] [%c{1}] [%M:%L] - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <priority value="debug" />
        <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender" />
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Comment: And add `<appender class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender" name="file">
        <param value="/tmp/spring.log" name="File"/>
        <param value="1" name="MaxBackupIndex"/>
        <param value="1MB" name="MaxFileSize"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" name="ConversionPattern"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>` in case you need to send log's also to a file(e.g. /tmp/spring.log) :)